# Nesting CSS classes for use with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the correct way to nest classes for use with Javascript?

I have an animated header using jQuery, that shrinks after 175px on the page; I also want its opacity to go down using `background: rgba()` (not `opacity:;`).

Unfortunately Bootstrap uses two separate divs and classes for the `background-color` and `height`. One class is `.navbar-default` which affects the colour, the other is `.navbar-brand` which affects the height.

Here is my code:

JS: as you can see, I've set `.shrink` to be added to `.navbar-brand` and `.navbar-default` when scrolling past 175px. Else, the `.shrink` class is removed.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var shrinkHeader = 175;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
        $('.navbar-brand, .navbar-default').addClass('shrink');
      }
      else {
        $('.navbar-brand, .navbar-default').removeClass('shrink');
      }
    });
    function getCurrentScroll() {
      return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
  });
</script>
```

HTML: This is a typical Bootstrap navbar layout.

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container navbarfix">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll svg" href="link">
            <!-- logo code here -->
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- links here -->
        </div>
      </nav>
```

SASS: This is my SASS code, which is very similar to CSS so I'm sure you can work it out.

As you can see the shrink class should change the `height` and `background` of both nested classes, but it only changes the height. So my question is how do I format this correctly?

```
$header_l: 180px
$header_s: 105px

.navbar-brand
  height: $header_l
  transition: height 0.2s

.navbar-default
  background: rgb(241,241,242)
  background: transparent\9
  background: rgba(241,241,242,1)
  transition: all 0.1s

.shrink
  .navbar-default
    background: rgba(241,241,242,0.75)

  .navbar-brand
    height: $header_s
```

CSS (the SASS compiles to this)

```
.navbar-default {
  background: #f1f1f2;
  background: transparent\9;
  background: #f1f1f2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.1s
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.2s;
}

.shrink .navbar-default {
  background:rgba(241,241,242,0.75);
}

.shrink .navbar-brand {
  height:105px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.shrink .navbar-default {
    background:rgba(241,241,242,0.75);
}
```

This is finding elements with the `.navbar-default`  class *under* the shrink class. So, it's basically assuming you have a structure of

```
<div class=shrink> 
    <div class="navbar-default">
    </div>
</div>
```

What you want instead is for it to apply to elements with both `shrink` and `navbar-default`, so you can do

```
.shrink.navbar-default {
    background:rgba(241,241,242,0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion:

The other classes over-power .shrink's settings

Try this:

After the value of a setting add "!important" without quotes or spaces which prioritizes this setting over all same level classes.

Code:

```
.shrink {
   Background: rgba(241, 241, 242, 0.75)!important;
   Height:105px!important;
```

}

Also Daniel makes a very good point:

When you put a space between classes in selection(.shrink .navbar-default) it looks for child elements with .navbar-default inside parent elements with .shrink. Removing the space should select element with both classes simultaneously.

:)

Let me know how it goes, Im on a 10 hour bus ride. I got time.

- KA